# Каптча в Yii

Tags: php, yii

Собственно наткнулся на такую проблему, я использую каптчу и все работает как нужно все окей.

Далее мне понадобилось каждые 15 секунд делать обращения к серверу на другой модуль, что бы получать статистику. И если пользователь в води каптчу и как раз попадает в то время, когда идет запрос к серверу, получается забавная история:

Валидация модели проходит, а вот save() выбивает ошибку. (я знаю, что сейв вызывает валидацию еще раз и походу любой пост запрос к серверу обновляет каптчу).

Если же отключить 15 секундные пост запросы к серверу, то все хорошо. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Если валидация проходит успешно, то логично будет вызывать save(false), чтобы при сохранении модели повторная валидация не производилась. Также в rules для капчи можно прописать scenario ('on'=>'ScenarioList'), чтобы исключить её валидацию при других запросах